# "Undefined size" error when defining a vector containing TTF_Font variables in C++

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I have tried defining a vector within a class containing a number of TTF_Font variables like so: `std::vector<TTF_Font> *fonts = &std::vector<TTF_Font>();` This gives me an error that states, "'_TTF_Font *const ': unknown size." I have also tried adding an integer inside of the parenthesis to define a size, but this doesn't help. Additionally, I have defined multiple other variables in the same fashion (e.g. `std::vector<int> *xposes = &std::vector<int>();`) and they work perfectly fine. Any idea as to what I could do to get the vector containing fonts to work (preferably without having to define a size)?

Comment: Why are you creating pointers to temporary objects?

Comment: I suppose because I forget about `nullptr`'s existence and the compiler wouldn't let me put just `std::vector<int> *xposes;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a vector object using `std::vector<int> *xposes = &std::vector<int>();` will not work correctly, because `xposes` is set point to a temporary object, that gets destroyed right afterwards. In some simple cases the program might still run correctly depending on the compiler, but it is undefined behavior because the vector object's destructor was called, and `xposes` is a dangling pointer pointing to an object that no longer exists.

Instead `std::vector<int> xposes;` should be used.

`TTF_Font` is an opaque type, meaning it is a `struct` whose definition is not available. So only pointers `TTF_Font*` can be used by a program using SDL_ttf. The error message means that `sizeof(TTF_Font)` does not work, and because of this it is not possible to create an `std::vector<TTF_Font>`. Instead a vector of pointers `std::vector<TTF_Font*>` would work.

Comment: `&std::vector<int>()` shouldn't compile to begin with.

Comment: The reason I am assigning them to a temporary pointer like that is because later, before any of them are used, in a function within the class, I have them point to new non-temporary vectors to avoid the values of the vectors defined in the class from being scope-locked. In other words, if we change one of the vectors defined in the class to a different vector inside of a function, won't the class vector only equal the new vector in the scope of that function, even if that function is a part of that class?

Comment: If the pointer not being used yet, it is better to initialize it with `std::vector<int> *xposes = nullptr;`

Comment: If inside a function, `std::vector<int> *xposes` always defines a *local variable*, and the identifier `xposes` refers to that variable for the rest of the block (until the `}`). 

If there is a class data member of the same name, it is not affected if you change the local `xposes`. The data member can still be accessed using `this->xposes` or `MyClass::xposes`. (Or normally by its name, when there is no such conflicting definition.)

Changing the value of a data member inside a function changes it permanently, not just for the scope of the function.